# Anime where the protagonist has a long lost friend who loves him

Tags: deadman-wonderland

It's about a kid that looks and sounds around about 10 years old. He is special for some reason, and has to go through challenges or something. Also he has this long lost childhood friend that loves him. She is pale with white hair and wears like a white jump suit and like red mitts on her hands. She's super powerful and is always protecting him even when he doesn't realize it. The anime is also pretty bloody (so gore possibly). He is also shown never to believe in himself but people around him do.

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I read here, this is probably [Deadman Wonderland](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6880/Deadman_Wonderland)

[image: Deadman Wonderland]

> Ganta is the only survivor after a mysterious man in red slaughters a classroom full of teenagers. He's framed for the carnage, sentenced to die, and locked away in the most twisted prison ever built: Deadman Wonderland. And then it gets worse.
>
> At Deadman Wonderland, convicts are forced into brutal deathmatches for the amusement of the masses, the cheers of the crowd drowning out the screams of the dismembered. Even when Ganta befriends Shiro, an unusual female inmate, his dark fate crushes all hope —until he discovers the strange ability to wield his spilled blood as a weapon. Ganta learns his new skill might be related to the murderous man in red and uncovers disturbing secrets that could expose those who stole his freedom. He's determined to see justice served —but first he'll have to fight for his life in a prison that holds a million ways to die.

From MyAnimeList

Comment: y'all are awesome! haha!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds exactly like Deadman Wonderland. The characters you're describing are Shiro and Ganta. Shiro being the white haired childhood friend and Ganta the main character that sounds and looks like a 10-year old. Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadman_Wonderland

[image]